# How to make text with a character limit responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs positioned as table cells. The second div contains a long string of text, but I want it to have a character limit.

The problem is it's not responsive. As I reduce the size of the page, the text runs off the page due to the whitespace.

How do I get the text to wrap around, maintain its ellipsis, and character limit, while not pushing the image on the left out of view while doing so?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/weebs/pen/WdZQeY

```css
.alert {
  background: #ebeef2;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 70px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.thumbnail img {
  height: 70px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100ch;
}

.thumbnail,
.title {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://custom1tester.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/5/4/115467141/lake-irene-1679708_orig.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="title">In ridens invenire sit. Vel ponderum vulputate ex, mel no erant dissentias interpretaris. Amet dicat possit vel eu, habeo vivendum senserit duo no. Duo ne alii facete inciderint.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think `ch` means what you think it does here. You have set the width of `title` using `ch`- in your case giving the div a width equal to 100 zero (0) characters... It's not clamping the text at 100 characters.

Comment: The length unit `ch` doesn't actually count characters. It takes the width of a zero `0` in the current font and multiplies it by the value supplied. If you have `100ch` and a single zero `0` is `2.5px` then the width of your element would be `250px`. For the ellipsis, as far as I know, you need `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap;` for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add on the wrapper div (.alert) the following css:

- [table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout): fixed; // so the `tables` size doesn't depend on it's contents
- width: 100%;

also, you can add on '.thumbnail img' 'max-width: 100%' so the image doesn't get bigger than it's parent.

https://codepen.io/bogdanpetru/pen/MrEaOa

Comment: @hungerstar My solution seems to work, can you please tell me what I am mising? :)

Comment: _"How do I get the text to **wrap around**, maintain its ellipsis, **and character limit**, while not pushing the image on the left out of view while doing so?"_ Your solution does not wrap and does not enforce character limit.

Comment: The table-layout provided the solution! I'm okay with the text not wrapping, but it's responsive and doesn't push the image off screen. I also forgot to add display:table to the parent (.alert). Thanks, @bogdanpetru!!